# Calling a model's function once Odoo server start

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have built a module in Odoo 8 to do some work. Suppose that there are two part of the module, one is **Pusher** (say) and another is **Worker** .

Pusher task is to insert current time into a database table **TAB_DATA**.

Worker is responsible to check table **TAB_DATA** and print each item of a table.

So here is the the scene :-

```
        TAB_DATA :-
--------------------------
time      |     touched 
--------------------------
```

Event 1.Clicked Button1 -> Call Pusher -> Insert t1 to **TAB_DATA**

Current Status :-

```
        TAB_DATA :-
--------------------------
time      |     touched 
--------------------------
   t1            false
```

Event 2.Clicked Button1 -> Call Pusher -> Insert t2 to **TAB_DATA**

Event 3.Clicked Button1 -> Call Pusher -> Insert t3 to **TAB_DATA**

Event 4.Clicked Button1 -> Call Pusher -> Insert t4 to **TAB_DATA**

Current Status :-

```
        TAB_DATA :-
--------------------------
time      |     touched 
--------------------------
   t1            false
   t2            false
   t3            false
   t4            false
```

5.Clicked Button2 -> Call Worker -> Read **TAB_DATA** WHERE touched = false -> 4 record found, print each and mark their touched to true

Current Status :-

```
        TAB_DATA :-
--------------------------
time      |     touched 
--------------------------
   t1            true
   t2            true
   t3            true
   t4            true
```

6.Clicked Button2 -> Call Worker -> Read **TAB_DATA** WHERE touched = false -> 0 record found, print Nothing

Now I converted Worker into background job to keep running and doing their work as a thread . Because of that Worker will keep checking the table TAB_DATA and do a print if a record found with touched = false.

Now finally my question is that let say Pusher inserted 100 records and anyhow Odoo server closed (Any reason). When Odoo server will come online (someone/script started server ) it should call Worker to start doing their job without clicking on Button2.

I checked with Odoo cron job but my worker code are executing as a thread so I need to manage Environment for current thread which requires **self.env** to get instance of new cursor and at the time of Odoo cron **self.env** is not available.

What can be other alternative way to implement it .

### **EDIT**

worker.xml

Here is the code of cron job

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="csv_importer_cron_worker" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Worker/field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
            <field name="interval_number">2</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall" eval="False" />
            <field name="model" eval="'mymodule.logger'" />
            <field name="function" eval="'start_work'" />
            <field name="args" eval="'()'" />
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

myworker.py

```
class MyWorker(models.Model):

    _name = "mymodule.logger"

    def start_work(self, external_task = None):

        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(self.pool.cursor(), SUPERUSER_ID, self.env.context)
            cur = env.cr

            # More codes like as get those records whose touched = false
            # etc.
```

Comment: Could you provide the code relevant to your Odoo cron job?

Comment: @dgeorgiev Please check my updated question .